# Php 5.6.5 won't work very well

Tags: php, debian, php56

Today I installed `Php 5.6.5` on my server running **Debian 7 Wheezy** and **Apache2**.

First, I added these repositories to my **/etc/apt/sources.list** file:

```
http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56
http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
```

Second, I added a **missing key** with these commands:

```
apt-get install debian-keyring
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys ***[the_key]***
gpg --armor --export ***[the_key]*** | apt-key add -
```

Finally, I installed Php 5.6.5 with this command:

```
apt-get install php5
```

Then I checked the Php's version with the command **php -v**, and the terminal returned the right version.

So I created an example php page to make a test.
Its directory is `/var/www/index.php` and its code is it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But it doesn't work, it shows a completely blank page.

I tried with other Php scripts, but it converts the php code to plain text.

Where's the problem?

What should I do to fix it?

**Here's the solution**

I enabled the apache module for Php with this command:

- `a2enmod php5`

Then I restarted the apache service and now everything works fine.

Comment: check the error logs for the web server - php is probably configured not to display them.

Comment: How can i check them?

Comment: `tail /var/log/apache2/error_log` (or similar)

Comment: actually, from your description apache probably doesn't have the php module, and it just serving php files as text. The phpinfo one just looks like blank XML to a browser.

Comment: In that file there are these logs:
http://pastebin.com/880tXAih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have php, but not the apache module for php

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

You may need to enable the module...

```
a2enmod php5
```

Restart apache and you should be good to go.

Without this module, apache doesn't do anything special with PHP, and just passes it through as text. You saw a blank page for `<?php phpinfo() ?>` as that looks like an empty XML document (view source will reveal all)

Comment: It says the newest version is already intalled.
But it says also that it set to manually installed.

Comment: is it enabled? see a likely looking symlink in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load ?